# How to get all data if day is less than or equal to 5th of every month in pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I want to check if salary is credited before 5th of every month on a streaming data.

**code**

```
Salary['date'] = pd.to_datetime(Salary['date'], format='%d-%m-%y')
sum_Salary = Salary.groupby('date').sum()
print("\nSalary received per month \n", sum_Salary)
```

Dummy input

Salary received per month

```
    Date   Salary
07-06-18  15300.0 
07-07-18  15300.0 
03-08-18  14783.0 
04-09-18  16249.0 
05-10-18  14448.0 
06-11-18  15663.0
```

Expected Output

```
Date   Salary

03-08-18  14783.0 
04-09-18  16249.0 
05-10-18  14448.0
```

FYI :

```
print(type(Salary['date']))

# class 'pandas.core.series.Series'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:
First you need to convert the `Date` column into Pandas Datetime:

```
In [2612]: Salary.date = pd.to_datetime(Salary.date, format="%d-%m-%y")
```

Now, `df` will look like this:

```
In [2632]: Salary
Out[2632]: 
        Date   Salary
0 2018-07-07  15300.0
1 2018-08-03  14783.0
2 2018-09-04  16249.0
3 2018-10-05  14448.0
4 2018-11-06  15663.0

In [2633]: Salary[Salary['date'].dt.day <= 5].groupby('date')['Salary'].sum()
Out[2633]: 
Date
2018-08-03    14783.0
2018-09-04    16249.0
2018-10-05    14448.0
```

I suppose this is what you want.